# Microsoft Graph Login not showing the Permission Requested

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

Good morning guys,

I'm implementing a Microsoft Authentication, that part goes good, the problem is when I get the user access_token, that token does not contain the requested permissions I chose in the Azure App. In the image below you can see the Permission I'm requesting in the Azure App.

[image]

In the next image you can see the permissions I'm obtaining with the login.
[image]

This is the code to request the access_token in my Startup.cs file.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddControllersWithViews();

     services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
         .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
             {
                 Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                 options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                 {
                     var accessToken = context.SecurityToken as JwtSecurityToken;
                     if (accessToken != null)
                     {
                         var claimsIdentity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                         if (claimsIdentity != null)
                         {
                             claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", accessToken.RawData));
                         }
                     }
                 };
             })
         .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
         .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
     services.AddMvc(option =>
     {
         var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
         option.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
     }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
 }
```

and this in the code in my appsettings.json

```
"AzureAD": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
  "TenantID": "common",
  "ClientID": "916xxxxxx-xx-3f7",
  "ClientSecret": "xxxx",
  "CallbackUrl": "./signin-oidc",
  "SigoutcallbackUrl": "./signout-oidc"
}
```

I also decoded my token and the permissions I'm requesting in the Azure App (image 1) are not in the token I get.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token you get from `OnTokenValidated` is the [ID token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/id-token-claims-reference) but not the access token, that's why you can't get the permissions you requested. In the mean time, when we need to generate an access token which containing required scopes(the permissions you added in AAD), we need to define the scopes when obtaining the token. You can take a look at the [common flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) in Azure AD, all of them require "scope" parameter.

When we need to obtain access token in asp.net core mvc app, we could integrate related libraries. We could have codes below.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
    }).EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "user.read", "Calendars.ReadWrite" })
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Then in the controller which having `Authorize` attribute, we could inject `ITokenAcquisition` and use it to generate access token.

```
private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;

public HomeController(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
{
    _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
}

 public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
 {
     var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "User.Read" });
     return View();
 }
```

Without sign in ahead would get error below, if we sign in successfully, this service would generate access token for us.

[image]